# PHP - How to search through multiple two-dimensional arrays and change values within them?

Tags: php

So I have tried a number of different things to get this working, but basically I am trying to loop through / search ten arrays, ten times. I have 10 rows and 10 locations within them for a 10x10 Battleship game. These arrays are the board, and they are two-dimensional arrays. I am comparing a move for a game taken in (text form) from the user against these arrays, and altering the grid based on whether they hit the ships or miss. For example, row 1:

```
$row1 = array(array(" O ", " A1"), array(" O ", " A2"), array(" O ", " A3"), array(" O ", " A4"), array(" O ", " A5"), array(" O ", " A6"), array(" O ", " A7"), array(" O ", " A8"), array(" O ", " A9"), array(" O ", "A10"));
```

If user enters A1, then $row1[0][0] should become " X ".

First, I tried a nested for loop to search and then update the board. I thought I could get away with doing $row$i as I did it in another PHP project but it's not working.

```
global $row1, $row2, $row3, $row4, $row5, $row6, $row7, $row8, $row9, $row10;
$move = $_GET["move"];
$i = 0;
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
for ($j = 0; $j < 10; $j++) {
if ($move == $row$i[$j][1]) {
$row$i[$j][0] = " X ";
}
}
}
```

Then, I tried the bulky way of breaking it into if statements. But for some odd reason, it only works on the 10th iteration.

```
for ($j = 0; $j < 10; $j++) {
if ($move === $row1[$j][1]):
$row1[$j][0] = " X ";
elseif($move === $row2[$j][1]):
$row2[$j][0] = " X ";
elseif($move === $row3[$j][1]):
$row3[$j][0] = " X ";
elseif($move === $row4[$j][1]):
$row4[$j][0] = " X ";
elseif($move === $row5[$j][1]):
$row5[$j][0] = " X ";
elseif($move === $row6[$j][1]):
$row6[$j][0] = " X ";
elseif($move === $row7[$j][1]):
$row7[$j][0] = " X ";
elseif($move === $row8[$j][1]):
$row8[$j][0] = " X ";
elseif($move === $row9[$j][1]):
$row9[$j][0] = " X ";
elseif($move === $row10[$j][1]):
$row10[$j][0] = " X ";
else:
endif;
}
```

I'm lost. This is for a homework assignment due tomorrow night.

Comment: Instead of a thousand arrays as rows, you might want to use a cleverer associative array instead and set its value through indexex, without the need of a loop, since you know exactly what cell you need to set or unset. Are you forced to use all these arrays as a starting point or did you declare them on purpose?

Comment: I don't have to use them as a starting point. How would you use an associate array instead?

Comment: answered below, it's just a couple of line of codes actually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For such a simple case, here are my 2 cents:

Since your case is a sort of a matrix (but a very very very basic one), the EASIEST solution, in my opinion, is just this:

```
$matrix = array ();

for ($i = "A"; $i <= "L"; $i++) {
   for ($c = 1; $c <= 10; $c++) {
    $matrix["{$i}{$c}"] = "O";
   }
}

$move = "A1";

$matrix[$move] = "X";

print_r($matrix);
```

$matrix is an array, and we're looping from A to L (PHP supports the ++ operator on letters), and we are making the array so that EACH element will literally be a target (or a cell).

The array output is this:

```
Array
(
    [A1] => O
    [A2] => O
    [A3] => O
    [A4] => O
    [A5] => O
    [A6] => O
    [A7] => O
    [A8] => O
    [A9] => O
    [A10] => O
    [B1] => O
    [B2] => O
    [B3] => O
    [B4] => O
    [B5] => O
    [B6] => O
    [B7] => O
    [B8] => O
    [B9] => O
    [B10] => O
    [C1] => O
    [C2] => O
    [C3] => O
    [C4] => O
    [C5] => O
    [C6] => O
    [C7] => O
    [C8] => O
    [C9] => O
    [C10] => O
    [D1] => O
    [D2] => O
    [D3] => O
    [D4] => O
    [D5] => O
    [D6] => O
    [D7] => O
    [D8] => O
    [D9] => O
    [D10] => O
    [E1] => O
    [E2] => O
    [E3] => O
    [E4] => O
    [E5] => O
    [E6] => O
    [E7] => O
    [E8] => O
    [E9] => O
    [E10] => O
    [F1] => O
    [F2] => O
    [F3] => O
    [F4] => O
    [F5] => O
    [F6] => O
    [F7] => O
    [F8] => O
    [F9] => O
    [F10] => O
    [G1] => O
    [G2] => O
    [G3] => O
    [G4] => O
    [G5] => O
    [G6] => O
    [G7] => O
    [G8] => O
    [G9] => O
    [G10] => O
    [H1] => O
    [H2] => O
    [H3] => O
    [H4] => O
    [H5] => O
    [H6] => O
    [H7] => O
    [H8] => O
    [H9] => O
    [H10] => O
    [I1] => O
    [I2] => O
    [I3] => O
    [I4] => O
    [I5] => O
    [I6] => O
    [I7] => O
    [I8] => O
    [I9] => O
    [I10] => O
    [J1] => O
    [J2] => O
    [J3] => O
    [J4] => O
    [J5] => O
    [J6] => O
    [J7] => O
    [J8] => O
    [J9] => O
    [J10] => O
    [K1] => O
    [K2] => O
    [K3] => O
    [K4] => O
    [K5] => O
    [K6] => O
    [K7] => O
    [K8] => O
    [K9] => O
    [K10] => O
    [L1] => O
    [L2] => O
    [L3] => O
    [L4] => O
    [L5] => O
    [L6] => O
    [L7] => O
    [L8] => O
    [L9] => O
    [L10] => O
)
```

Now, once you get the target ($_GET['move'] in your case) you already know that it will exist inside the array, so you just replace its value using `$matrix[$move] = "X";`

Output:

```
Array
(
    [A1] => X
    [A2] => O
    [A3] => O
    [A4] => O
    [A5] => O
    [A6] => O
    [A7] => O
    [A8] => O
    [A9] => O
    [A10] => O
    [B1] => O
    [B2] => O
    [B3] => O
    [B4] => O
    [B5] => O
    [B6] => O
    [B7] => O
    [B8] => O
    [B9] => O
    [B10] => O
    [C1] => O
    [C2] => O
    [C3] => O
    [C4] => O
    [C5] => O
    [C6] => O
    [C7] => O
    [C8] => O
    [C9] => O
    [C10] => O
    [D1] => O
    [D2] => O
    [D3] => O
    [D4] => O
    [D5] => O
    [D6] => O
    [D7] => O
    [D8] => O
    [D9] => O
    [D10] => O
    [E1] => O
    [E2] => O
    [E3] => O
    [E4] => O
    [E5] => O
    [E6] => O
    [E7] => O
    [E8] => O
    [E9] => O
    [E10] => O
    [F1] => O
    [F2] => O
    [F3] => O
    [F4] => O
    [F5] => O
    [F6] => O
    [F7] => O
    [F8] => O
    [F9] => O
    [F10] => O
    [G1] => O
    [G2] => O
    [G3] => O
    [G4] => O
    [G5] => O
    [G6] => O
    [G7] => O
    [G8] => O
    [G9] => O
    [G10] => O
    [H1] => O
    [H2] => O
    [H3] => O
    [H4] => O
    [H5] => O
    [H6] => O
    [H7] => O
    [H8] => O
    [H9] => O
    [H10] => O
    [I1] => O
    [I2] => O
    [I3] => O
    [I4] => O
    [I5] => O
    [I6] => O
    [I7] => O
    [I8] => O
    [I9] => O
    [I10] => O
    [J1] => O
    [J2] => O
    [J3] => O
    [J4] => O
    [J5] => O
    [J6] => O
    [J7] => O
    [J8] => O
    [J9] => O
    [J10] => O
    [K1] => O
    [K2] => O
    [K3] => O
    [K4] => O
    [K5] => O
    [K6] => O
    [K7] => O
    [K8] => O
    [K9] => O
    [K10] => O
    [L1] => O
    [L2] => O
    [L3] => O
    [L4] => O
    [L5] => O
    [L6] => O
    [L7] => O
    [L8] => O
    [L9] => O
    [L10] => O
)
```

Another valid solution is using an array structure such as:

```
Array (
       [row] => Array ([letter] => value)
      [...]
)
```

So that you can easily sort rows later, but for such a basic case it is, in my opinion, unneeded.

(Or, you could also do the opposite association: letter -> array (1 => value, [..]))

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++){
echo "This is Row:".$i."<br/>";
for($j=1;$j<=10;$j++){
    echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;This is Cell: {$j} in Row: {$i}<br/>";
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$row1 = array(1,2,3);
$row2 = array(4,5,6);
$row3 = array(7,8,9);

var_dump(
    ${'row' . 1},
    ${'row' . 2},
    ${'row' . 3}
);
```

Mmm?

Answer (score -1):

Based on your first example you should be able to do something like the following:

```
global $row1, $row2, $row3, $row4, $row5, $row6, $row7, $row8, $row9, $row10;
$move = $_GET["move"];
$i = 0;
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
  for ($j = 0; $j < 10; $j++) {
    if ($move == $row$i[$j][1]) {
      $rowvariable = $row . $i;
      $$rowvariable[$j][0] = " X ";
    }
  }
}
```